# Different behaviour when an application is called by a service from the SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, security, windows-7, permissions, .net

When executing an application as a user account (with admin privileges), everything works as it is supposed to.

However, when calling a service which executes the same application, but from the `SYSTEM` account, the application runs as it is supposed to, however it does not find any ODBC or printer drivers. To allow the service to call the application, I am using [the following code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite?fid=1539607&fr=31#xx0xx).

I would imagine that the SYSTEM account has full privileges and can do anything which the administrator user account can do. The only thing I can think of is something going on in the linked code, when switching the session from 0 to 1, so that the application can appear in the user's desktop.

What could the problem be?

Comment: `I would imagine that the SYSTEM account has full privileges and can do anything which the administrator user account can do` - It depends on what you mean by administrator.  The system account has all privileges on the local machine only.  It has almost zero access to network services.  `ODBC or printer drivers` - ODBC settings can be stored per-user or per-machine.  If you are storing them per-users then the system account cannot use them because it has a different profile.  Printer connections to network printers are all per-user.

Comment: This isn't surprising.  The local system has only a minimal user hive, not designed to support high-level functionality such as printing and ODBC.  The bottom line is that you probably won't be able to do this; use a real account instead.